# Initializing members in a Constructor

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

Let's assume a simple class like this

```
class MyClass {
  String aString;
  DateTime aDate;

  MyClass({this.aString = '', this.aDate = DateTime.now()});
}
```

This code **does not work**  because optional parameters must be constant. I do **not** want `aDate` be nullable.

I can do this:

```
class MyClass {
  String aString;
  DateTime aDate;

  MyClass({this.aString = ''}) : this.aDate = DateTime.now();
}
```

This is accepted by the compiler **but** I cannot set `aDate` when constructing an instance of `MyClass` like so:
`var c = MyClass(aString: 'bla bla', aDate: DateTime(2021, 9, 20));`

Instead it seams I have to write:

```
var c = MyClass(aString: 'bla bla');
c.aDate = DateTime(2021, 9, 20);
```

**Is there really no better way to initialize complex objects with optional named parameters in constructors with null safety turned on?** This is just a simplified sample. In reality, I have classes with lots of complex objects that I get from a remote server. The method shown above forces me to write hundreds of lines of assignment statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```dart
class MyClass {
  String aString;
  DateTime aDate;

  MyClass({this.aString = '', DateTime? aDate}) : aDate = aDate ?? DateTime.now();
}
```

You were on the right track, you just needed to combine the two methods you provided above. This uses an optional named parameter, which must be nullable, and only assigns it to `this.aDate` when it's not `null` using the `??` operator. If it is `null`, it uses your desired default value of `DateTime.now()`.